# Excel interop doesn't accept ranges with commas

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._worksheet.range.aspx) of `Workbook.Range`, you can provide commas in the first argument to provide an union.

However, the following code throws a `COMException` with HRESULT `0x800A03EC` on the line that gets the range:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void RangeWithCommas() {
    var excel = new Application();
    var wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    var ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    var range = ws.Range["A1,A2"]; // this throws an exception
    Console.WriteLine(range.Address[false,false]);

    ws.Delete();
    wb.Close(false);
    excel.Quit();
}
```

How can I do or fix this?

P.S. I am aware of [Application.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.union.aspx) but I would very much prefer not to use it because there is no easy way to provide a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Did you check if its a problem with your locale? To be more precise your list separator. Go to your regional settings in Control Panel and check. Then run the code with the set list separator. Btw. Wouldn't "A1:A2" do the trick?

Comment: @AnalystCave.com In this case `A1:A2` would indeed be identical, but in the case of e.g. `A1,E8,F100` it wouldn't. And that's exactly why i need it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **AnalystCave.com** pointed out, some Excel COM methods are locale specific. You need to use the regional list seperator when accessing the COM method.

This code should work correctly on all locales:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void RangeWithCommas() {
    var excel = new Application();
    var wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
    var ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

    var rangestring = String.Join((string)excel.International[XlApplicationInternational.xlListSeparator], new [] {"A1","A2"});

    var range = ws.Range[rangestring];
    Console.WriteLine(range.Address[false,false]);

    ws.Delete();
    wb.Close(false);
    excel.Quit();
}
```